# External Authentication security level (SCP03) and the expected data for them

Tags: authentication, smartcard, apdu

I am trying to do External authentication on SMART CARD, using SCP03. The value of P1 is the security level that we are using for the authentication.
May I know the possible values of the security levels and the data I need to pass for them?

Comment: You should restrict *code* markup to code. I also don't recognize a relation to PCSC, even if that is the API you use. Otherwise I suggest that you attempt to digest the global plattform specification first and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow this

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, there are three security level for command apdu:

1. none: nothing is secure
2. mac: command is clear but mac of command is calculated and added to the  command
3. enc: command is encrypted and mac of command added to thecommand

there are another two option for response security:

4. rmac: like mac for response apdu
5. renc: like enc for response apdu

I suggest you to study Globalplatform specification:
https://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp